# How to fix '403 Client Error: Forbidden for url' error in Free Music Archive API with python

Tags: python, api, audio, bigdata

FMA has stopped providing the key, so I got it from other netizen.
These keys code are 'CFEFES9JPKBN4T7H' and 'R2FNSRG1D3FGDKG6'.
I guess these keys might don't have enough permissions to let me download the track, or FMA turned off this service.
Anyone with experience can solve the problem?

I have tried to simply load some information from API, such as tracks, albums and artists. They had no problems.
Contains** fma.get_track(), fma.get_track_genres() and fma.get_album()**.

```
fma = utils.FreeMusicArchive(os.environ.get('FMA_KEY'))
track_file = fma.get_track(2, 'track_file')
fma.download_track(track_file, path='track.mp3') #error 403
```

According to the agreement, I should be able to download the track as'track.mp3' to the local.But it showed a error msg to me.

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://files.freemusicarchive.org/music/WFMU/AWOL/AWOL_-_A_Way_Of_Life/AWOL_-_03_-_Food.mp3
```

Comment: Those keys are very old that you've provided and because they are open on the net, they are most likely deactivated. That's what I would do at least if I wanted to keep the bandwidth down on my API.

Comment: Yes, their agreement has a content to express this problem. thanks your comment.